# Providing additional evidence to prosecutor

Tags: assault, battery

My question is this: My Granddaughter (allegedly) attacked her mother, and caused several injuries including one that will require surgery to her face. Is it possible to ensure that evidence is provided to the prosecutor? She has already been released on her own recognizance with misdemeanor charge, awaiting court appearance, but the court does not have any of this evidence. All they have are the pictures the LE officer took. Thanks.

Comment: In what jurisdiction did this occur? Different countries and states have different rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could provide evidence either to the law enforcement officer on the case, or to the prosecutor. The prosecutor will decide which evidence to present at trial if there is a trial. Sometimes a victim's advocate or defense counsel, as they case might be, can facilitate this process.

Comment: we have contacted the victims advocate, and she is helping us with this issue. Thank you.